# Appending keys and values

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class intDict(object):
    """A dictionary with integer keys."""

    def __init__(self, numBuckets):
        """Creates empty dictionary."""
        self.buckets = []
        self.numBuckets = numBuckets
        for i in range(numBuckets):
            self.buckets.append([])

    def addEntry(self, dictKey, dictVal):
        """Assumes dictKey an int. Adds an entry."""
        hashBucket = self.buckets[dictKey%self.numBuckets]
        for i in range(len(hashBucket)):
            if hashBucket[i][0] == dictKey:
                hashBucket[i] = (dictKey, dictVal)
                return
        hashBucket.append((dictKey, dictVal))

    def getValue(self, dictKey):
        """Assumes dictKey an int. Returns entry associated with
           the key dictKey."""

        hashBucket = self.buckets[dictKey%self.numBuckets]
        for e in hashBucket:
            if e[0] == dictKey:
                return e[1]
        return None

    def __str__(self):
        result = '{'
        for b in self.buckets:
            for e in b:
                result = result + str(e[0]) + ':' + str(e[1]) + ','
            return result[:1] + '}'

import random

D = intDict(29)
for i in range(20):
    key = random.randint(0, 10**5)
    D.addEntry(key, i)
print "The value of the intDict is: "
print D
print '\n', "The buckets are: "
for hashBucket in D.buckets:
    print ' ', hashBucket
```

Could someone explain it to me what is that `addEntry(self, dictKey, dictVal)` does? And how.
I'm new to programming in general, following John Guttags Introduction to Computation and Programming using Python, and currently stuck at this.
Btw, `print "The value of intDict is: "`, when run, prints only 29 empty lists. Why is that?

Comment: What is it you don't understand? Your question is too broad. Try to narrow it down.  Please understand, Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial service. One quick bug, though, is that I believe your `return` statement in `__str__` needs to be outside the for-loops. It's currently inside the outermost for-loop.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing `result[:1]` should be `result[:-1]`